# 图片 and 照片: are they interchangeable?

Tags: word-choice, vocabulary

I see both words used on modern websites.  Do 图片 and 照片 mean the same thing?  Are there cases where they are not interchangeable?

Comment: `图片` means picture, `照片` means photo, i.e. pictures taken by camera.

Comment: There will always be situations when ２ different expressions are not interchangeable. Therefore 
rather than asking whether 2 expressions are interchangeable why not ask when they are interchangeable? （In the present case there clearly are contexts when they are：bkrs：图片：image picture photograph CL:张[zhāng]).Alternatively ask whether they mean the same thing.总是会有两个词句不可互换的情况。

因此，与其问两个词句是不是可互换的，不如问什么时候（在什么情况下）（它们）是可互换的。(此例中显然有时这两个词是可互换的）.或‌​者另一种选择,问该两个词句意思是不是一‌‌​​样的。 总的来说

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, they are not interchangeable.

照片 is only the ones taken with a camera. 图片 can be any picture.

Answer (score 2):

no,照片=photo,图片=picture,照片是用相机拍摄下来的，而图片可以是绘画等